# Why isn't += adding to the variable's value?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using solve_ivp & the generalized Lotka-Volterra equation to calculate changes in species' populations over time. In the code, the equation is split into two parts as shown below:

```
species = ['fox','rabbits','deer']

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
first_ABC = solve_ivp(ecoNetwork, (0, 10), X0,  t_eval = t, args=(interactionStrength, growthRate), method = 'RK23')

def ecoNetwork(t, X, interactionStrength, growthRate):
    # define new array to return
    output_array = []
    # loop through all the species
    for outer_index, outer_species in enumerate(species): 
        # grab one set of growth rates at a time
        amount = growthRate[outer_species] * X[outer_index]
        for inner_index, inner_species in enumerate(species):
            # grab one set of interaction matrices at a time
            amount += (interactionStrength[outer_species][inner_species] * X[outer_index] * X[inner_index]) 
        # append values to output_array
        output_array.append(amount)
    # return array
    return output_array
```

However, the "amount +=" part of the code is not working as expected and doesn't seem to be adding the second part of the equation to the first. It works if I change the line to a new variable name, e.g.

```
amount2 = amount + (interactionStrength[outer_species][inner_species] * X[outer_index] * X[inner_index])
```

Can someone explain why the += isn't working?

X0 and growthRates are both pandas dataframes and the interaction matrix is formatted like this:

```
                fox   rabbit         deer 
fox          0.000000  -1           0.000000 
rabbit       1         0.000000     0.000000 
deer         0.000000  0.000000     0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't really say why `+=` is not working, but it's a special operator that would have to be defined in the class of the specific data type stored in `amount`.

If you say that

```
amount2 = amount + (interactionStrength[outer_species][inner_species] * X[outer_index] * X[inner_index])
```

works, then I would believe that

```
amount = amount + (interactionStrength[outer_species][inner_species] * X[outer_index] * X[inner_index])
```

would do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Python variables store references to objects instead of their values. Therefore, either you will need to use another variable (as in your case amount2) or use "copy" module to create a shallow copy of amount. (cleaner solution)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html